# Add multiples css-property box-shadowes to one element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a box-shadow  with several commands to an element.
IF I do it using css, it is very easy:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red; /* css */
```

But I can't figure out how to do it using only javascript.

```
element.style.boxShadow= '0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red'; /* javascript */
```

It doesn't work.

It is as if the command only can contain one "line" of css:

```
element.style.boxShadow= '0px 0px 5px green';
```

(this works, but I want more ...)

I've tried to put box in plural - for fun ;)

```
element.style.boxShadows= '0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red';
```

OR using another seperator:

```
element.style.boxShadow= '0px 0px 5px green;|[space] 0px 0px 5px inset red';
```

But always with same dissapointing result ...

How to fix this?

**EDIT: I've made a stupid typo:**
The command is - of course - not shadowBox, but boxShadow. Sorry for those who answered the question, thinking that my problems was here
BUT it doesn't change my challenge ...

**SECOND EDIT**
I can't say why, but the code IS actually working. I've reviewed my code and can't say why it was not working before ... sorry

Comment: Try with `object.style.boxShadow = "none|h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color |inset|initial|inherit"`  please refer this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_boxshadow.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's boxShadow, not shadowBox or shadowBoxes.

```
    var element2 = document.getElementById("show-editor-button");
    element2.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red";
```

[image]

2. If you have more than 1 element use any loop to apply on all else it will do nothing.

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('js-vote-down-btn');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++){
        elements[i].style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red";    
    };
```

[image]

You can try this code by running it in the console of this page itself.

To understand more on box-shadow => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: You are right about the inversion of the boxShadow command (a typo) ;) But it doesn't resolve my initial question.

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if you still face the issue. Although, It's working here in the console.

Comment: Now it is working as it should. I can't say why, because my CODE has always been using the boxShadow command. But it was your answer to just do it again, which did the job. So I can only say that my initial question was already working. But thanks for giving hints.

Answer (score 0):

why not use class?

css

```
 .mystyle{shadow-box: 0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red;}
```

html

```
<div id="myDIV"></div>
```

javascript

```
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Comment: I want only a js-solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

The property for JavaScript is boxShadow rather than shadowBox.

```
element.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 5px green, 0px 0px 5px inset red';
```

This should work for you.

Comment: You are right that I inversed the box and shadow, but it was a stupid typo. My problem is still there ...